# BeanCreationNotAllowedException from @PreDestroy annotation from PrometheusPushGateway in Spring Boot 2.0.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using the [PushGatewayConfiguration](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/83b4639d3c3bb378fcc8ce9ec444007e93a4cc94/micrometer-spring-legacy/src/main/java/io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.java#L105) with a few minor changes to configure the PrometheusPushGateway.

The PrometheusPushGateway is set to send metrics at the end of a task through the @PreDestroy annotation. In Spring 2.0.3 the PushGateway works fine, but in Spring 2.0.5 I am getting a stack trace from the PushGatewayHandler.shutdown() call.

Generally, what I think is going on is there are singletons being removed during the DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons() method call.

I've noticed there are Singletons being removed in 2.0.5 that the PushGatewayHandler.push() relies on that weren't being removed in 2.0.3. I'm struggling to resolve the issue and suggestions are appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'channelRemoteTaskOut': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:208) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:514) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.support.management.IntegrationManagementConfigurer.lambda$registerComponentGauges$1(IntegrationManagementConfigurer.java:395) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.internal.DefaultGauge.value(DefaultGauge.java:40) ~[micrometer-core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
        at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$newGauge$3(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:230) ~[micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
        at io.micrometer.prometheus.MicrometerCollector.lambda$collect$0(MicrometerCollector.java:81) ~[micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at io.micrometer.prometheus.MicrometerCollector.collect(MicrometerCollector.java:82) ~[micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
        at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:183) ~[simpleclient-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:216) ~[simpleclient-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:137) ~[simpleclient-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:22) ~[simpleclient_common-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway.doRequest(PushGateway.java:290) ~[simpleclient_pushgateway-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway.pushAdd(PushGateway.java:171) ~[simpleclient_pushgateway-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at com.build.task.batch.metrics.PushGatewayHandler.push(PushGatewayHandler.java:57) [api-task-batch-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.build.task.batch.metrics.PushGatewayHandler.shutdown(PushGatewayHandler.java:70) [api-task-batch-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152-ea]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:156) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:240) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:571) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:504) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1041) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1017) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:967) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at com.build.task.customer.CustomerAnalyticsApplication.main(CustomerAnalyticsApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration` really has an issue:

> (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)

The `shutdown()` calls a `push();` which performs a `DefaultGauge.value()` eventually and that one is exactly like the lambda in this call:

```
this.metricsCaptor.gaugeBuilder("spring.integration.channels", this,
            (c) -> this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MessageChannel.class).size())
            .description("The number of message channels")
            .build();
```

According that fix in Spring Framework we can't call `getBean()` from the `BeanFactory` during its destruction.

I don't see straightforward fix for your unless to disable that `PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration` via `management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=false` and copy/paste the content of that class to your own and replace a `@PreDestroy` with the `ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>`. This one is going to be called before beans destruction. See `AbstractApplicationContext.doClose()`:

```
 try {
            // Publish shutdown event.
            publishEvent(new ContextClosedEvent(this));
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
           ...
        }

        // Destroy all cached singletons in the context's BeanFactory.
        destroyBeans();
```

And also, please, raise an issue against Micrometer project to fix this problem in the `PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration` the way I suggest for you.

Comment: Edit: I ended up needing to extend a TaskExecutionListener instead and leverage the onTaskStartUp, onTaskFailed and onTaskEnd methods.